# Cannot get ssl connections working Python 3.6.3 os X High Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, https

So I've been at this all night and I can't seem to fix it.

The problem is that I can't establish https connections in Python3. A basic example:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
http.request("GET", "https://community.letsencrypt.org/")
```

Which gives the result:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x103844d30>
```

This gives the same result for https://google.com but twice, I'm assuming because of a redirect.

- I've installed the certifi package
- I've run the Install Certificates.command
- I've reinstalled python3 (I use homebrew)
- I've checked the cert.pem link in,
- I've installed the python.org python3 package (to see if it wasn't something homebrew did)
- I've checked if the cert.pem links were correct in /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem (homebrew) and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/etc/openssl/cert.pem (python.org local install)

My best guess is that it can't find the root certs, but they are right there, freshly installed with the certifi package

The original thing I was working on was getting mqtt working again with an ssl connection.

Comment: Can't you just use requests? It solves 95% of these types of problems.

Comment: Sadly, no. Since paho-mqtt doesn't use it (which is my goal)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an Urllib3 problem. I had it on other devices as well.